# How do I set the value of a property in every row of an array using LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have this array:

```
App.selectedPhrases.Pts
```

What I would like to do is to set the value of the int `selected` property to `0` for every row in the array.

Is this something that would be good to do in LINQ or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The Q in linq stands for **queyring**, not **modifying**. What is the prblem on a normal loop?

Comment: @Alan2 Provide the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES**, it´s posible,

**BUT**

you don´t gain much in contrast to a good-style old loop, e.g.:

```
foreach(var instance in myCollection)
    instance.selected = 0;
```

You can also use the `ForEach`-extension on `List<T>`, which however looks pretty similar and does the exact same thing. While you don´t gain *any* advantage, this solution forces you to materialize your collection into a list. However here is it:

```
myCollection.ForEach(x => x.selected = 0);
```

The Q in Linq stands for **querying**, not **modifying**. That´s why Linq is good to retrieve objects, e.g from a database, but not to update those objects.

Comment: Isn't `myCollection.ForEach(x => x.selected = 0);` slower than an *old-style* loop to execute?

Comment: @Cid Why should it? Anyway faster and slowly allways depend the contex.t. Do you you consider 1 nanosecond to be **noticable**? Or negotiabale?

Comment: This was a *real* question. I've heard that linq is slower, but I don't know in which context